# Replacing all occurrences of a string in JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript

I have this string:

```
<Tracking event="firstQuartile"><![CDATA[]]></Tracking>
<Tracking event="firstQuartile"><![CDATA[]]></Tracking>
<Tracking event="firstQuartile"><![CDATA[]]></Tracking>
<Tracking event="firstQuartile"><![CDATA[blah blah bla]]></Tracking>
```

i try:

```
.replace(new RegExp('<Tracking event="firstQuartile"><![CDATA[]]></Tracking>', 'g'), ' ');
```

and nothing happened. I dont understand why.

Comment: You have to escape the special characters, e.g. `[` and `]` like this: `\\[`, `\\]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `[` typically opens up a class of characters, so you need to make it just a plain character:

https://jsfiddle.net/hwtu29eg/

```
s.replace(new RegExp('<Tracking event="firstQuartile"><!\\[CDATA\\[]]></Tracking>', 'g'), ' ');
```

The reason you need `\\` is that you need a single `\` in the string (as the final result in the string), and if you use `\[` that merely quotes the `[` and becomes `'['`.  Because `'\\'` in the code will become a string of `'\'`, therefore to make it `'\['`, you need `'\\['` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex literal escaping `/` and `[]` meta-symbols:

```
var str = '<Tracking event="firstQuartile"><![CDATA[]]></Tracking><Tracking event="firstQuartile"><![CDATA[]]></Tracking><Tracking event="firstQuartile"><![CDATA[]]></Tracking><Tracking event="firstQuartile"><![CDATA[blah blah bla]]></Tracking>';

console.log(str.replace(/<Tracking event="firstQuartile"><!\[CDATA\[\]\]><\/Tracking>/g, ' '));
```

The output:

```
"<Tracking event="firstQuartile"><![CDATA[blah blah bla]]></Tracking>"
```